# Bin by multiple months in altair?

Tags: python, altair

This code creates a bar chart binned by month.

```
# Load libraries
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

# Load data
df = data.seattle_weather()

# Create chart
alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
    x='month(date):T',
    y='mean(temp_max)')
```

Is is possible to bin by every "n" months? For example, each bar would be the data from two months (Jan+Feb, Mar+Apr, June+July... etc).

[image]

Comment: VegaLite added a [`step` parameter to time units in 4.10.2](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/timeunit.html#example-customizing-step), so Altair will eventually be able to use these to customize the time step to exactly 2 months for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only built-in multi-month binning is the `quarter` [time unit](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/transform/timeunit.html#user-guide-timeunit-transform); for example:

```
alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
    x='quarter(date):O',
    y='mean(temp_max)'
)
```

[image]

If you wanted something more customized, you can use a [calculate transform](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/transform/calculate.html) including an appropriate [vega expression](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/expressions/) to group results as you'd like. For example:

```
alt.Chart(df).transform_calculate(
    group='month(datum.date) < 4 ? "Jan-Apr" : month(datum.date) < 8 ? "May-Aug" : "Sep-Dec"'
).mark_bar().encode(
    x='group:O',
    y='mean(temp_max)'
)
```

[image]